# Node that was "touched" wasn't actually touched

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, touch-event

i trying to make an app with spriteKit in which when the user touched a sprite node, there's a NSLog message that says that the node was touched.
I tried to do it with comparing the name of the touched node with the name of the node that i check if was touched. The problem is that the system recognise that the node was touched although it wasn't touched. I think that there is a problem with the node area, the system thinks that a node is somewhere while it's absolutely not.

```
-(void)selectNodeForTouch:(CGPoint)touchLocation
{
    if([[touchedNode name] isEqualToString:@"menuPlayButton"]){

        NSLog(@"Pressed");
        }
}
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];

        [self selectNodeForTouch:positionInScene];


    }
}
```

Any ideas what might the problem be?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The code does not select a node based on the touch location and you did not include the code that assigns touchedNode.

Answer (score 0):

Your `selectNodeForTouch:` method is completely wrong. It uses `touchedNode` variable, which is not defined anywhere in the code you posted. This method should look like this:

```
- (void)selectNodeForTouch:(CGPoint)touchLocation
{
    NSArray *nodes = [self nodesAtPoint:touchLocation];
    for (SKNode *node in nodes) {
        if([node.name isEqualToString:@"menuPlayButton"]) {
            NSLog(@"Pressed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work yet..Still, when i presses somewhere on the screen sometimes it prints "Pressed" although i didn't pressed the node...any other suggestion?

Comment: May be menuPlayButton is very very big?

Comment: Yes it is too big, do you know how to make it smaller without ruining the image actual size? thanks

Comment: menuSettingsButton = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"menuSettingsButton"];
            menuSettingsButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)-100);
            menuSettingsButton.name = @"settingsButton";
            [self addChild:menuSettingsButton];

Comment: *menuSettingsButton is being declared i the .h file.

Comment: What is a size of `menuSettingsButton` image?

Comment: i have created it with photoshop

Comment: the size is 500X500, i've tried to resize the sprite size but the image is being shrinked